# Terminal closes at once when started

Tags: configuration, gnome-terminal

When I am using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or starting the Terminal app from the menu, Terminal appears for a second and suddenly closes. I have to work with `xterm` for now. I know this behaviour was made by my misconfiguration. How can I restore my Terminal to its initial state?

Comment: This is happen only when you oppen it with Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut?

Comment: no its for the entire Terminal application

Comment: Hi @Tanmoy. Can you edit your question and add the output of running the command `gnome-terminal` inside an `xterm`?

Comment: after giving a "gnome-terminal" again the terminal crashes or hides like previous time

Comment: @Tanmoy Is there no text output in `xterm` after running `gnome-terminal`? (No error message?) If so, please put that text in your question.

Comment: am sorry, nothing shown in the output. just a black terminal screen suddenly seen to be closed.

Comment: Try running the command `gnome-terminal --tab -e "exec /bin/bash -i"` and see if it still disappears.

Comment: @Tanmoy:  If nothing helps you then try this.. 1. Press ctrl+alt+F1 to go to `tty1` CLI mode. Then execute these commands: `sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall gnome-terminal` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-terminal` Then again press ctrl+alt+(F7 or F8) to come back to GUI mode and check whether your problem solved or not.. Try to restart your system once..

Comment: thanks.. this is done, from there i was able to change the profile preference in which there was an auto command "pwd" was executed each time, thanks!

Comment: well then ask @htor to post it as answer.. and then accept his answer, it will help others to solve their issue..

Comment: thanks @htor ,  
 
Try running the command gnome-terminal --tab -e "exec /bin/bash -i" and see if it still disappears.  make this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command and see if it still disappears:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "exec /bin/bash -i"
```